# Aggregate selected rows as total in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex query which provides output as below.

```
Name Date       Value1 Value2
D    1493803432  12    14
S    1493803424  20    15
T    1493804556  30    12
Y    1493823445  44    13
```

My desired output is to add row to this as sum of two or more rows, here I have given only two to reproduce the need

```
Name Date    Value1   Value2
D    1493803432  12    14
S    1493803432  20    15
T    1493803432  30    12
Y    1493803432  44    13
TY   1493803432  74    25
```

So it's sum of two rows where Name in 'T'&'Y' and adding that to the same output as new row

Comment: What is your logic for deciding when to sum rows, and which to sum? And how will you decide which 'date' value to show? You say you're adding it as a new row, but you also seem to be omitting the original rows you're summing.

Comment: If you are already summing the values is your complex query, why not substitute the values "T" and "Y" for the value "TY". Your summing would result in a total sum.

Comment: my logic is by name where name is in  T,Y then it will aggregate those two and add as row to the same. 1st output is not doing this, 1st output is the 1st table given above

Comment: But you've said you've shown those two as an example, and there may be more than two. An answer specific to just those two might not be helpful.

Comment: @D14 what about the date for TY row? Why is it `1493804556`?

Comment: @ Nitish corrected the table , yes the date should be same across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the original version of the question:

```
WITH your_complex_query ( Name, "Date", value1, value2 ) AS (
  -- insert your complex query here
)
SELECT LISTAGG( NAME, NULL ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY NAME ) AS NAME,
       MAX( "Date" ) AS "Date",
       SUM( Value1 ) AS value1,
       SUM( Value2 ) AS value2
FROM   your_complex_query
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name IN ( 'T', 'Y' ) THEN 0 ELSE ROWNUM END;
```

To answer the updated version of the question:

```
WITH your_complex_query ( Name, "Date", value1, value2 ) AS (
  -- insert your complex query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   your_complex_query
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TY',
       MAX( "Date" ),
       SUM( Value1 ),
       SUM( Value2 )
FROM   your_complex_query
WHERE  name IN ( 'T', 'Y' );
```

Comment: if we need to group the aggregation by time.. what needs to be done